# Excel - switching names in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have a list of peoples names in one column, showing first names first.
I want to sort them in alphabetical order of surnames.
Is there a way of doing that without changing the text around, and if not is there a quick way to swap the text without retyping?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to sort based on surname, but I can help you format your data in such a way to obtain sorting by last name:-

1. Assuming your column has two words separated by a space, insert a column next to (to the right of) your current name column. (If you have more than two, say n space-separated words, insert n-1 columns)
2. Select the column with the names, go to Data -> Text to Columns -> Select Delimited -> Next -> Select just "Space" as your delimiter -> Next -> Finish
3. Now that your names are split into two (or more) columns, create another column next to them. I'll assume Column A and Column B have your data, and C is the newly inserted column, but you can easily adapt this for more columns.
4. In C1, type =CONCATENATE(A1, " ", B1) and press enter. (If you had more names, you would type =CONCATENATE(A1, " ", B1, [" ", C1, ...]))
5. Select cell C1, and use the little box on the bottom right of the cell and drag it down to the last row of C.
6. Sort your data using the last name column, making sure the other columns also get sorted.
7. Now hide columns A and B.

Comment: Just be careful if you have people with more than two names in your list.

Comment: @Kyle I'll edit the answer to explicitly mention this. Thanks.